# Why is Getx not working even after adding navigation key

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to use Getx to navigate from my main page, but this time, I'm calling the Getx method outside the buildContext, and every time I run `Get.to(()=> NextPage());` I keep getting the error message

**Error Message**

> You are trying to use contextless navigation without
> a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
> If you are testing your app, you can use:
> [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
> a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
> for a [GetMaterialApp].

**but the Navigation Key is added to the  GetMaterialApp**

```
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  runApp(
    UncontrolledProviderScope(
      container: container,
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MyApp(),
        navigatorKey: Get.key,
        // navigatorKey: _navKey,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: This is one example of why contextless concepts that GetX introduced are just problematic.

Comment: hmm @RandalSchwartz, which approach do you suggest i can use to resolve this?

Comment: Stop using GetX.  Use standard techniques for navigation. These are well-documented and mature.

Comment: like i said in my question, i'm trying to navigate from the main.dart page and method its outside the BuildContext.

Anytime i use the standard navigation provided by `Flutter` i get `Undefined name 'context'`

Comment: @Zionnite That's by design. You should not call a navigation method if you have no `BuildContext` in that scope. GetX is violating this and hence causing many problems

Comment: hmm, interesting, so please tell me @DhafinRayhan how you would handle this situation. You are getting data from Firebase Messaging Background and upon a certain argument received, you would want to Navigate to another Screen, remember you are totally not inside BuildContext blocks now

Comment: @Zionnite Navigation does not have to be imperative; you can use a declarative routing solution like [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). Also maybe that's worth a separate question, I believe many people have done that mechanism before (make sure you search first if there are existing questions on that topic already)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `navigatorKey: _navKey` and Use `Get.to` to navigate to the next screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        navigatorKey: _navKey, // Use _navKey for navigation
        home: const HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Use Get.to to navigate to the next screen
            Get.to(() => const NextScreen());
          },
          child: const Text('Go to Next Screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Next Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Use Get.back to navigate back
            Get.back();
          },
          child: const Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have done that too, but it didn't work

Comment: I edited the answer and If you are using the latest version of `getX` then It should work.

Comment: I updated to `get: ^4.6.6` and my code yet issues persist

Comment: this answer did not work for me and i'm using the latest package